# The term 'recruiter' being used incorrectly

Tags: discussion

Eg This answer: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/23683/17187

I've seen it a few times, the term 'recruiter' being used to refer to the hiring manager at the employing firm.

My understanding is that a recruiter is someone who works independently of the employer, acting as a middleman to find talent for the employer to interview.

Is my understanding correct, if so, and what term should be used here instead?

Answer (score 11):

There are two kinds of recruiters (at least in my experience in the US).  Third-party recruiters are (or work for) independent agents that have both companies and job-seekers as clients; they win when they match these up, and they work on commission.  This is the more common use of the term.

But some companies also have in-house recruiters, people who work for that company and have, as a primary job function, finding and filtering candidates for open positions.  They may be salaried employees.  My last employer had such a person, and Google has several (judging from my LinkedIn mail); those are but two data points.  So it's not correct to say that a recruiter always works independently of the employer.

All that said, the recruiter is *definitely* different from the hiring manager.  This case sounds like a mistake.  Feel free to offer an edit to the post to correct the reference.